# How to make a dependency use a patched version of its dependency?

Tags: composer-php

My project has a `vendor1/dep1` dependency. This package has its own dependency `vendor2/dep2`. The last package had a bug that I fixed and sent my patch back as a pull request. But the maintainer doesn't respond and I want to use my patched version of this sub-dependency.

To do so I had to fork a `vendor1/dep1` package, change its `composer.json` to:

```
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/me/dep2"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "vendor2/dep2": "dev-master",
```

and commit it to the `patched-dep2` branch.

After that I updated my project `composer.json` as well:

```
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/me/dep1"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "vendor1/dep1": "dev-patched-dep2",
```

Very tricky, and it doesn't work. I have no idea why. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`repositories` settings are ignored from dependencies - this setting takes effect only for `composer.json` of root project. So your settings in `vendor1/dep1` fork are ignored.

You need to define repositories for these two forks in `composer.json` of your main project:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/me/dep1"
    },
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/me/dep2"
    }
],
"require": {
    "vendor1/dep1": "dev-patched-dep2"
}
```

But in your case you should be able to alter this without forking `dep1`:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/me/dep2"
    }
],
"require": {
    "vendor1/dep1": "1.1.1",
    "vendor2/dep2": "dev-master as 1.1.2"
}
```

Where in place of `1.1.1` and `1.1.2` you should use real versions for these packages. `dev-master as 1.1.2` should override constraint from `dep1` and composer should use master branch from your fork.

Comment: This was the right solution for me, I was having an issue depending on the usage of `dev-main` for the dependency that I was working on. The alias fixed it.. Actually I wasn't aware of this possibility in composer. Cheers